# How can I modify this regex pattern to also remove spaces after a newline \n?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have a string with excess whitespace. I want to remove any whitespace at the start of each line up to the color. I also want to preserve single spaces between words, not affect colons if they don't precede a percentage (look at the `Pastels` in the string for an example) and the number of spaces after the colon (1 space for double digits, 2 spaces for single digits). So far I'm preserving everything I want, but I'm not able to get rid of single spaces after the `\n`.

How do I remove all whitespace after a new line and at the start of the string in one pattern?

I want the string to look like this: `'Red: 80%\nNavy Blue: 15%\nGreen:  3%\nPastels: Pink, Baby Blue, Lavender:  2%'`

```
my_string = '    Red: 80%\n Navy Blue: 15%\n  Green:  3%\n   Pastels: Pink, Baby Blue, Lavender:  2%'

my_pattern = re.compile('(?<![:])[ ]{2,}')    # match 2 or more spaces unless they follow a colon

# the following:
re.sub(my_pattern, '', my_string)
# returns this:
'Red: 80%\n Navy Blue: 15%\nGreen:  3%\nPastels: Pink, Baby Blue, Lavender:  2%'    # Note the number of spaces after the colons and newlines. 
                                                                                    # The space before "Navy Blue" is the problem.

# this would give me the desired result, but what pattern would let me do it all within one re.sub() ?
re.sub(my_pattern, '', my_string).replace('\n ', '\n')
# returns this:
'Red: 80%\nNavy Blue: 15%\nGreen:  3%\nPastels: Pink, Baby Blue, Lavender:  2%'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove only horizontal whitespace chars from the start of each line, you can use

```py
my_pattern = re.compile(r'(?m)^[^\S\r\n]+')
my_pattern = re.compile(r'^[^\S\r\n]+', re.M)
my_pattern = re.compile(r'^[^\S\r\n]+', re.MULTILINE)
# and then use my_pattern.sub:
text = my_pattern.sub('', text)
```

Note the `(?m)` inline modifier flag is equivalent to `re.M` option, it is handy when you can use a regex in some function/method that is defined in some linked library, and you do not want to import `re` module to just be able to use the flag.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^\S\r\n]+` - one or more (`+`) occurrences of any char but (`[^...]` is a negated character class) a CR (carriage return, `\r`), LF (line feed, `\n`) and non-whitespace char (`\S`). So, this is the same as `\s+` with LF and CR chars subtracted from it.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t7LA8I/1).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Far simpler than I was originally thinking:

```
my_pattern = re.compile('(?m)^\s+')    # (?m) sets to multiline mode
                                       # ^\s+ matches any whitespace immediately following the start of a line

# a little cleaner way of writing the same thing:
my_pattern = re.compile('^\s+', re.MULTILINE)

# the following:
re.sub(my_pattern, '', my_string)
# returns:
'Red: 80%\nNavy Blue: 15%\nGreen:  3%\nPastels: Pink, Baby Blue, Lavender:  2%'
```

Comment: Does it mean you also want to remove empty lines?

Comment: I suppose this would do that. Those don't exist in my data but if they did then I would want to remove them.